# Create a new template for twentytwelve

Tags: page-template, theme-twenty-twelve

[Twenty Twelve](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentytwelve) comes with some page templates: Front Page & Full Width.  These are in the folder /page-templates.

I've created my own template and saved it into this folder, but it is not present to be selected when editing a page.

There is no mention of the two page templates in functions.php

What do I need to do to include my new page template?

Comment: Add the header (the first lines) of your template to the question.

Comment: FYI, you should be doing all this in a child theme so you don't lose your changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the template file in your theme and add the following comment to the top of your file after the

```
/**
 * Template Name: This is the name of your template
 */
```

WordPress will pick this up and in the page templates dropdown you will see "This is the name of your template" listed as an option

Answer (score 1):

According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

what you need to place at the top of the template file is

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Template File
*/
?>
```

and then the template will show up in the Template drop down in Page Attributes meta box and you'll be able to select it.

And, you should be working with a child theme, too, in order to not lose your changes and templates when twentyeleven is updated. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes