# How to include custom post type posts on a page?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, pages

I need help adding a Portfolio page to one of my main Pages. I don't know what information is needed, so I'll just throw in some of the important stuff.

Basically I have my main menu, (Welcome, About, Contact, etc.) which includes a tab called 'Work'. Under that tab, I have two pages called Portraits and Modeling. I want to somehow insert a few portfolio pages (each with a separate photo shoot) into the Modeling page. Ideally, I want it to show a one image preview and the full shoot once clicking on the image.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to add a new [page template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67747/385), which is a copy of the template that you already use for your pages.

Then simply add [a new loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/385):

```
$portfolio_items = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    // ''               => '', # Other arguments here
) );
if ( $portfolio_items->have_posts() )
{
    while ( $portfolio_items->have_posts() )
    {
        $portfolio_items->the_post();
        // Example output:
        the_thumbnail();
        the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```